# How do I test Relaycommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, rhino-mocks, relaycommand

I'm reading this
[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) about MVVM. I'm currently looking at the RelayCommand in figure #15. Pretend I wanted to test this SaveCommand. How would I do that? I'm using NUnit and Rhino Mocks 3.6

Comment: In your test, `viewModel.SaveCommand.Execute(object parameter)`.  Then, check your Model and see if you get the desired results.

Answer (score 5):

`RelayCommand` is just another `ICommand` implementation, so to fire the command you just call `Execute()` on the relay command instance that is exposed by your viewmodel, and pass in any args.

Since the SaveCommand you mention takes no args you can fire it with:

```
MyViewModel.SaveCommand.Execute(null);
```